# why is ${} in texteditor not supported?

Tags: javascript, string-literals

when i write this code in vs:

```
const firstName = "Mohamed";
const lastName = "Eldamaty";
const sentence = 'Hello ${firstName}' ;
console.log(sentence);
```

the result is `Hello ${firstName}`
I want to concatenate it with first name
any body help me to fix this problem

Comment: use back ticks \` in sentence instead of '

Answer (score 1):

You have to use backticks instead of normal quotationmarks.

```
const firstName = "Mohamed";
const lastName = "Eldamaty";
const sentence = `Hello ${firstName}` ;
console.log(sentence);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using template strings, so absolute value is being logged. Do this:

```
const sentence = `Hello ${firstName}` ;
```

Use backticks (`) to use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).